# Sparx EA for SysML - Expecting that changes to a BDD will affect also an IBD

Tags: enterprise-architect, sysml

Hi EA SysML mavens,

1. I create a BDD, and it has a block; call the block B1. I give B1 two ports.
2. I create an IBD diagram.
3. I drag the block B1 (from Project Browser) onto the IBD diagram. It appears with the two ports.
4. I later decide I need a 3rd port on B1. So I go back to the BDD diagram and add a 3rd port.
5. I then look at the IBD and expect that it now has 3 ports. it does not.

**Question:** Why does the IBD diagram now still have just 2 ports instead of 3 ports?

Comment: It has three ports, they are just not showing on the diagram I guess

Comment: As Geert said you need to show the embedded new port. Depends on your (not stated) EA version where to find that.

Comment: EA version 15.1
 - avraham

Comment: I should have asked the question more clearly..So here ....  Question: Why does the IBD diagram now have just 2 ports instead of 3 ports?

Comment: Please edit the question rather than making comment. Thanks!

Comment: >> Please edit the question rather than making comment. Thanks!
Done.
(Now I learned that it is possible to edit the original question.)

Comment: :-) Please also add the version info in the question. It's important that questions are complete for later referenece. Comments may (and these here will) be deleted by chance.

Comment: Reverse work automatically: Ports added to a part appear at the block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show newly created port instances manually.

[image]

In the above picture `Port1` was created with the instance if `Class1`. (Actually whether `/Port1` is directly shown changes with the weather Down Under or how Sparx implements it per versions.) Anyhow, `Port2` has been created after instantiation of `Class1`. So the Features window indicates that `/Port2` is not visible. Just set the tick mark and the port will be shown.

Comment: Actually there is no defined notation for ports on instance specifications. The orginal poster also asked about internal block diagrams. Your answer is true for ibds as well, though.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer EA has a so-called MDG (profile set) for SysML which I don't have. So I fell back to basic UML.